# How to block the selection of a sticker in iMessage

Tags: ios, imessage, msstickerview

I'm trying to make a very simple stickers iMessage application with user being proposed to in-app purchase when they click on some of the stickers.

I have a custom view controller that implements `UIViewController`, `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource` (source: https://github.com/jelenakrmar/customStickerApp).

I am now trying to override the default behaviour when the user taps or peels the sticker.

My first attempt was at the level of the collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// open the in-app purchase window
}
```

but it doesn't work

Maybe I would need to extend `MSStickerView` and do something in '`didTap`' and '`didLongPress`'.

Does anyone have some experience with overriding the behaviour of iMessage when selecting a sticker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, if your `UICollectionViewCell` has a `MSStickerView` (or possibly imports `Messages` framework), the `didSelectItemAt` delegate doesn't get called.

For example, if I wanted to have a Sticker Extension with free and locked stickers, I would create two different cells in my `UICollectionView`. One has a `MSStickerView` and the second one only has an `UIImageView`. If a free sticker is tapped, iOS handles everything with the `UICollectionView` delegate not being fired. However, if a user taps a locked sticker, the delegate will fire, and can be handled by the `didSelectItemAt` delegate.

I haven't found any documentation that points to this yet.

Comment: yes, I came to the same conclusion: you need 2 different kinds of cells one with MSStickerView the other with something else (eg UIImageView). The problem is that you can't animate a apng in a UIImageView. I tried to use a third party library for this but it ruined the performance and the app got rejected. I ended up using an UIImageView, this is not ideal of course (user cannot see the animated stickers running before buying them). I mark your answer as true.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation and have a UICollectionController loading stickers via a MSStickerView in my UICollectionViewCell.

I subclassed a UICollectionViewCell and placed a MSStickerView onto the cell contentView.  After this, I disabled touch by:

```
(stickerView)?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The collectionViewController function `didSelectItemAt` now works.